# calculate line height

Tags: geometry

Have a query. 
In the diagram, Line A (Black) is 18 inches, Line B (Blue) is 7.04 inches and bend angle is 13 degrees. Considering Line A and C are parallel to each other, How can I calculate the height between Line A and C.
Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXZOu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If the angle between A and B is 13 degrees, then you can use SOHCAHTOA since it's a right angle triangle, specifically SOH.

So height $AC = \sin(13)*7.14$

Equals approximately 1.61"